# Which is Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, delete

I'm trying to delete Ubuntu, but I can't find a way to locate Ubuntu partitions. In most threads, people just point out which one is which without saying how did they know. So I tried, and this is what I've got:

[image: ds command]

and this:

[image: GParted]

Comment: Just so you know, depending on where GRUB is installed, if you delete the Ubuntu partition before fixing the MBR through Windows, you *may* render your system unbootable...

Comment: I found that using the EasyBCD program is a good way to deal with this. Thank you for the warning!

Comment: I haven't used any of the proposed tools, but maybe this question http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/108339 is also helpful.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one `df` shows file systems used by Linux, although most are memory file systems (first column says `tmpfs` or `udev`).

The ones with `/dev` are real file systems, but Linux can mount non-Linux file systems too.

---

The second image is more meaningful, showing partitions on your hard disk. When you look at the third column (File System), you can see various types

- ntfs - Windows
- fat32 - DOS/Windows
- ext4 - Linux
- linux-swap - Swap space used by Linux (equivalent to swapfile.sys or pagefile.sys under Windows)

Comment: So I should delete the /dev/sda9 and /dev/sda6 ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can have more than one `ext4` partitions, also Linux can be installed onto different file system. So, the right is the one that is mounted on the root of the file system `/`.

Comment: @Wolf Yes and no, `/dev/sda9` is a Linux partition, but `/dev/sda6` is some NTFS/Windows partition. The one above, `/dev/sda10` is the Linux swap partition.

Comment: @SpasSpasov Where do you see a second `ext4` partition?

Comment: So the only one I should be deleting is /dev/sda9 and /dev/sda10 because the rest is also tied to Windows? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, the others are ntfs, fat32 or unknown, which are Windows data or system partitions.

Comment: Olaf, the question has and a principal answer, isn't it? :)

Comment: @SpasSpasov I misread your comment, and you're right of course. It could have been another partition.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda9 is the ubuntu partition. This contains ALL of your ubutntu files. the /dev/sda2 contains files required to boot the system.
Dont bother about the rest, their are partitions, created and mounted by running system (ds command output).

Partitions located in /dev/ are the "physical" partitions.

Comment: So the only one I should find in windows partitions manager and  delete is the sda9 (and sda6..?). Thank you.

Comment: sda6 is an ntfs  partition. The flag msftdata means it's a Windows partition. Maybe it's only your old movie collection, maybe it's something more crucial to the system. Linux programs are unlikely to be found there if you didn't put them there yourself.

Comment: why sda6? no, not the sda6. The above answer (by Olaf Dietsche) is a bit more precise, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

**Your Ubuntu installation is located as "/" seen from within Ubuntu** 
The Linux installation is mounted at "/". So you can identify the partition using its mount point "/". In this case sda9.

This is a simple answer as you can have components of your installation on several partitions (like your personal files).

The tmpfs indicated by df are temporary file storages.
Swap space is used by Linux as a way to store temporary data (for example some tmpfs data if RAM is low).

Deleting the "/" partition will delete Ubuntu. Be sure you know what you're doing. Deleting the Ubuntu partition doesn't mean everything will get back to the state before the Ubuntu installation. Extensive doc at https://ubuntuforums.org and https://help.ubuntu.com/ .

Comment: What about /dev/sda10? Shouldnt I delete Ubuntu Swap partition as well?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do next. You can always use a swap space (basically a reserved empty space) if you want to install one or several other linux distros after deleting ubuntu.
If you want to go on with only lets say Windows installations, then you can delete the swap space and reclaim the space.

Answer (score 0):

**Mount** the partition and check it's content and depending on your installation type the **home folder** should be there.